# Is it possible to migrate back from Amazon Aurora to native MySQL in Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I saw Amazon introduced new Amazon Aurora MySQL [migration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Migrate.html) from native MySQL to Amazon Aurora MySQL.

Would it be possible to migrate back from Amazon Aurora to regular MySQL with Amazon RDS?

Comment: Can you use `mysqldump` to export your database from Aurora and use that output to repopulate your MySQL database?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Amazon's Aurora is [MySQL wire compatible](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/) so you can always use tools such as [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) to get your data back out into a form that you could use to import back into a regular MySQL instance running in RDS, an EC2 instance or anywhere else for that matter.

Since posting this answer Amazon has also released the [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) which can be used to do zero downtime migrations between MySQL -> Aurora MySQL (Aurora also now supports PostgreSQL) and back. It also supports heterogeneous migrations such as from Oracle to Aurora MySQL or a number of other sources and targets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be more specific . To migrate from MySQL to Amazon's Aurora you just do migration in RDS console with a few clicks. I was wonder if it is possible to do vice versa. Migrate from Amazon's Aurora to MySQL from RDS console?

Comment: No, you cannot migrate from Aurora to MySQL from the RDS console. If you need to do a minimum-downtime migration from Aurora then you can use some of the replication options listed here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html

Comment: Nowadays, you can: "You can migrate data from any MySQL-compatible database (MySQL, MariaDB, or Amazon Aurora MySQL) using AWS Database Migration Service." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small database, you can use tools such as Navicat or MySQL Workbench to export the data out. For big databases, you can download aws cli either for Windows or Linux, for Linux it comes with a pre-installed on Amazon Linux AMI. Use **aws configure** to set up credentials and regions. Use **mysqldump** from the cli remember the **--single-transaction** option to avoid locking and take dump preferable from **slave replica**.

For a subset of the data, you can either use: (Windows example)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM database.table
WHERE ......
into OUTFILE '/location/of/path/dumpfile.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
Query OK....
```

to extract just what you need as flat files which is faster to load into any other MySQL env. You can also **setup permission to load into s3 as flat files** and export anywhere again if the file is not as big. But for huge data, please use mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

Percona has a [series of steps](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/07/04/how-to-setup-replication-between-aws-aurora-external-mysql-instance/) to follow that outlines how to set up a MySQL replica from an Aurora master. You'd then be able to take it to RDS MySQL from there. In some cases this manual method might make sense.

Overview:

1. Snap the Aurora instance
2. Bring up a temp Aurora instance
3. Dump it (mysqldump)
4. Create the replica
5. Migrate traffic

However as @ydaetskcoR suggests, Amazon has the tool and the use case defined for setting up such a replica with DMS. I'd start [here](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/#Continuous_Data_Replication) is a direct link to that use case.